# gatsbyjs - should I use GraphQL or not for images?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to use Saasland template into `gatsby`. I am new to `gatsby` and new to `graphql`  as well.

`layout.js`

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import "./layout.module.css"
```

`layout.module.css` has all the style classes from Saasland template. For images the css has:

```
background: url("../images/home5/shap_tecture.png")
```

I am already facing an issue with loading these images on a component (page).

From my previous question, I was told to follow https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-images/ to deal with images.

So, **How can I use GraphQL for images that are referenced in css as shown above ? Do I need to write a query for each image ?**

Comment: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2470#issuecomment-338394370

Comment: To elaborate on the @ksav 's link - if you want to leverage `gatsby-image` then yes and this link shows how to mimic background images using `object-fit`